# Textmate c++ compiling errors

Tags: c++, g++, compilation, textmate

When trying to compile a c++ file in textmate (this happens when clicking run), I get an error in a seperate window that says:

Can't find “g++” on PATH.

Theme:
The current PATH is:

/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/texbin
/usr/X11/bin
Please add the directory containing “g++” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.

Alternatively, the PATH can be retrieved from Terminal but this requires a relaunch: 
Set PATH and relaunch (button)

Clicking clicking Compile Single File to Tool gives a different error.
It says: "sh: g++: command not found".

Comment: have you installed the Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textmate is telling you that it cannot find the compiler (g++).

You should either move the g++ executable into one of the directories specified in the PATH variable, or add the directory containing the g++ executable to the PATH.

Comment: I found the g++ executable in /Developer/usr/bin, and I added a shell variable in the "advanced" section of preferences called "XCODE" with value "/Developer/usr/bin". Unfortunately, I still get the "sh: g++: command not found" error! Could you please help me?